# Problema con visualización de datos

Tags: r, pipe

Estoy aprendiendo R la función pipe. Quiero filtrar unos datos en función del mes del año. Sin embargo, al momento de querer visualizar la información me sale:

> Error: unexpected symbol in:
>
> "View(resumen)
>
> resumen"

No sé qué puedo hacer.

```
resumen<-data%>%
  select(FECHA,NUMERO.DE.CLIENTES,ENTIDAD)%>%
  mutate(cliente = as.numeric(substr(data$NUMERO.DE.CLIENTES,1,20),
         fecha = Date(data$FECHA,format="%m/%d/%Y"),
         anio = year(data$FECHA),
         mes = month(data$FECHA))%>%
    filter(mes<7)%>%
  group_by(ENTIDAD)%>%
  summarise_each(funs(
    media=mean(.),
    minimo=min(.),
    maximo=max(.)),NUMERO.DE.CLIENTES)%>%
arrange(mes)%>%
View(resumen)
```

Answer (score 2):

El pipe `%>%` es una herramienta que encadena funciones y que siempre traslada la salida de una, a la entrada de la siguiente, **siempre completando de manera automática el primer parámetro.**

En tu caso `View()` está dentro de un lote de funciones encadenadas por pipe, por lo que si lo que buscas es visualizar los datos finales, no necesitas indicar nada más, simplemente, haz `View()` o incluso solo `View`:

```
...
arrange(mes)%>%
View()
```

Ahora bien, si tu idea en realidad era agregar un titulo al visualizador de datos, ese es otro cantar, el titulo, es ,sí el segundo parámetro de `View()` y en este caso se espera una cadena:

```
...
arrange(mes)%>%
View("Resumen")
```